# How to enable/disable batch operations in Azure portal?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I need a way to enable/disable batch operations from the Azure portal.

This can be achieved programmatically or in Service bus explorer. The documentation is pretty simple and does not dive into specific configurations.

Comment: This property is not exposed via the portal, so you could not change it via portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are three ways you can create a queue in ASB, using portal, .Net library or ASB API. However, **Queue properties differ while creating from portal versus creating queue by .Net library/API**.

Azure portal limits the queue properties but there are lot **more useful properties available from Azure library**. Some of the useful properties available via  library are enabling batching, enable express which can be useful for performance improvements.

As George said, the batching property is not exposed via azure portal, you could use library and Servicebus Explorer to enable/disable it.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://rumanblogs.com/azure-service-bus-queues/).